# Mulitiple foreach bindings knockoutjs

Tags: knockout.js

I am using two foreach as below:

```
      <div class="sgMail" data-bind="foreach : mails">...</div>

      <div class="sgMail" data-bind="foreach : archived">..</div>
```

Here if i click on inbox , foreach: mails should be executed and other foreach archived shouldnot be executed.

How to do that ? Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question directly, you can use a flag to determine which to show:

```
<!-- ko if: showingArchived -->
<div class="sgMail" data-bind="foreach : mails">...</div>
<!-- /ko -->

<!-- ko if: !showingArchived() -->
<div class="sgMail" data-bind="foreach : archived">..</div> 
<!-- /ko -->
```

You may want to consider using one array and filtering it at the appropriate time. Knockout's binding will automatically update the interface. Also, you could use one `foreach` and apply the `if` bindings in the elements inside.

Comment: Yes, I would make it observable.